# A ajuda de formatação precisa de ajuda

Tags: bug, localização, central-de-ajuda

[Nossa página de ajuda de formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) tem problemas bem sérios. Na ordem em que os encontrei:

1. Falta o link para a [referência de sintaxe oficial do Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Eu aproveitaria o momento para trocar o link para o do [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)
2. **Não explica como formatar códigos em bloco ou inline!**
3. **Os exemplos estão todos quebrados!**. Melhor puxar a versão corrigida e revista da ["página de ajuda de edição avançada"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).
4. A parte dos magic links traduziu coisa a mais – o próprio nome de alguns magic links, e da maneira como estão lá eles não funcionam.

Seria uma página bem útil para indicar a novos usuários, mas como está fica complicado...

Comment: E o que propõe para consertar isso? O que precisa e como se pode ajudar? Talvez colocar cada uma das seções avançadas aqui como uma resposta e a gente vai editando até deixar resumido?

Comment: Na verdade não precisa propor muita coisa... O item 1 é simples, o 2 e 3 se resolvem copiando da outra página que indiquei, e o 4 é só olhar na nossa referência de magic links no faq da comunidade. O problema é que só o Gabe pode ajustar essa página, então precisamos aguardar a disponibilidade dele (acho que ele está com problemas de disponibilidade nesta semana e na próxima).